# output caching and resource files

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, localization

I have several .aspx page that use resource files, like this:

```
string TheLanguage = "fr"; //or "de", or "en" ... can be different for each request

CultureInfo newCulture = new CultureInfo(TheLanguage);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;
Page.Culture = TheLanguage;

string SomePageText = GetGlobalResourceObject("SomePage", "SomeResource").ToString();
```

As you can see, `TheLanguage` can change at runtime. If I implement output caching on this page, will the page be cached with the language that was determined when the page ran through its lifecycle, and then when a new request comes in for a different language the output will be that of the previous run or will the caching take the different languages into account?

Comment: How are you going to get the value of `TheLanguage` parameter for each request?

Comment: I get it from the URL from the HttpContext. The page is reached via www.mysite.com for en language and then the page is at www.mysite.com/de and www.mysite.com/fr for other languages

Comment: And are you using web forms or MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your inputs, here's how I was able to setup a working page:

I assume you already have a friendly route mapped like this; if not, then you can add it per your needs:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "{locale}", "~/default.aspx");
```

Then in `Page_Load` for `default.aspx.cs`, I get the language and assign the thread culture like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // "locale" is the query parameter that we defined in the route config. 
    // default the language to English if none is specified in the URL. 
    // E.g. www.mysite.com will default to English instead of throwing an exception.
    var language = Page.RouteData.Values["locale"] as string ?? "en";

    // set the language, culture etc. 
    var newCulture = new CultureInfo(language);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;
    Page.Culture = language;

    // do other stuff
}
```

In `default.aspx`, add the `OutputCache` directive (note how it refers to the same param name "locale"):

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByCustom="locale" VaryByParam="None" %>
```

In body:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Language</h2>
        <p>
            <%= Page.Culture %>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Last Updated</h2>
        <p>
            <%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
        </p>
    </div>

</div>
```

All we need to do now is override `GetVaryByCustomString` in `Application_Start` under `Global.asax.cs`:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    // let the base method handle everything else
    if (!custom.Equals("locale", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);

    // if the query param is "locale", return a string that varies with the value.
    // in our case, since we're setting `CurrentUICulture`, we can use its `Name`.
    return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;
}
```

Running this gives a me page cached for 60 seconds based on language used:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

how did you implement output cache? is this in .aspx file like this?

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="99999" VaryByParam="*" blabala....
```

if this, you can use VaryByCustom property to distinguish between different lanuage like so

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="99999" VaryByParam="*" VaryByCustom="language" blabala....
```

and add the following code to Global.asax

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
{
    if (arg == "language")
    {
        return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```